# Check if google suggests an autocomplete for some term

Tags: python, google-search-api

I want to write a python script that when given a term (string), will checks if google suggest an autocomplete for this term. In other words, it should checks if this is a known term. So I found a google API that can return URLs for a search of a term https://code.google.com/p/pygoogle/. It looks something like:

```
from pygoogle import pygoogle
g = pygoogle('quake 3 arena')
g.pages = 5
print '*Found %s results*'%(g.get_result_count())
g.get_urls()
```

But actually, I'm not interested in the URLs. I'm interested only if google suggests an autocomplete for the exact term or not.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can use combination of requests and bs4

Comment: @taesu Please explain. What do you mean?

Comment: Look at the ajax interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `urllib` to read suggests in XML format at [`http://suggestqueries.google.com/...q=quake%203%20arena`](http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=quake%203%20arena). Just replace the `q` parameter and parse content with [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree).

Comment: Interesting idea. What are the other params (`output` and `hl`)?

Comment: You can use `output=firefox` to get suggests as a JSON file. `hl` determines the language.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `requests` lib, install via:

`pip install requests`

then the code:

```
import requests

def get_suggestions(s):
        r = requests.get('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&hl=en&q={}')
        return r.json()[1]

for i in get_suggestions('firefo'):
        print i
```